# multiple parameter pack expansion by gcc and clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, variadic-templates

I am trying to use variadics to convert `N` parameters function to `2^N` parameters function. The following snippet compiles happily by `clang 3.9`, while `nvcc 8.0` (effectively `gcc 5.4`) fails miserably with the error:

```
error: no instance of overloaded function "foo" matches the argument list
```

code:

```
template<class... Ts> struct Typelist{};

template <class..., class... Us>
void foo(Typelist<>, Typelist<Us...>, Us... us ){
//  do the actual work
}

template <class T, class... Ts, class... Us>
void foo(Typelist<T, Ts...>, Typelist<Us...>, T t, Ts... ts, Us... us){
    foo(Typelist<Ts...>{}, Typelist<Us..., Us...>{}
        , ts..., us..., (us+t)...);
}

template <class... Ts>
void bar(Ts... ts){
    foo(Typelist<Ts...>{}, Typelist<unsigned>{}
        , ts..., 0u);
}
```

called like

```
int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])
{
    bar(2u);
    bar(2u, 3u, 4u);

    return 0;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? How do I make it work with `gcc`?

Comment: What's the full call that you're making? Shouldn't compile at all.

Comment: gcc 6.3.1 does not have a problem with this.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Really? It has a problem with this for me. Did you pass at least two args into `apply()`?

Comment: Yes. I checked it with two arguments and gcc 5.4. Although I stripped the code a bit for SO, will check once again.

Comment: @Barry - I assumed this was an MCVE. Obviously, it is not. Adding an explicit call revealed the problem. I see where the problem is.

Comment: `void _apply(Typelist<D0, Ds...> , D0 d0, Ds... ds, Is... is)` -- you have a non-last parameter pack. This function call cannot be deduced. See the duplicate question for more information.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No shit, maybe you should try that next time before posting that there's no problem?

Comment: Sorry, that is all my fault, I changed the code too much before posting and did not check it actually compiles. And then the thing which compiled did so with clang 4.8, not gcc... I screwed a lot of things here, so it is really great that Barry was able to provide the answer without seeing the actual problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code runs afoul of [temp.deduct.type]:

> The non-deduced contexts are: [...] A function parameter pack that does not occur at the end of the *parameter-declaration-list*.

as in:

```
template<class D0, class... Ds, class... Is>
HOST_DEVICE void _apply(Typelist<D0, Ds...> , D0 d0, Ds... ds, Is... is) {
//                                                   ~~~~~~~~
```

and [temp.arg.explicit]:

> A trailing template parameter pack (14.5.3) not otherwise deduced will be deduced to an empty sequence of template arguments.

This deduce-nondeduced-packs-as-empty idea breaks your code on both gcc and clang in different ways. Consider the call `apply(1,2)`:

- every version of gcc I've tried considers the `Ds... ds` pack empty and deduces `Ds...` as `<int>` and `Is...` as `<int, unsigned int>`. So that overload is thrown out as it takes 5 arguments and we're only passing 4.
- every version of clang I've tried deduces the second `Ds...` as `<int>` from the first argument and `<>` from the pack and consider the deduction to be a failure due to the inconsistency.

Either way, there's not really a path forward here.

---

What you can do instead is to flip the order and put all the `Is...` first. Since you know all the types, you can explicitly specify them, and let the `Ds...` be deduced. That is:

```
template<class... Is>
HOST_DEVICE void _apply(Is..., Typelist<>)
{
    // ...
}

template<class... Is, class D0, class... Ds>
HOST_DEVICE void _apply(Is... is, Typelist<D0, Ds...> , D0 d0, Ds... ds) {
    _apply<Is..., decltype(std::declval<Is>()+std::declval<D0>())...>(
        is...,
        (is+d0)...,
        Typelist<Ds...>{},
        ds...);
}

template<class... Ds>
HOST_DEVICE void apply(Ds... ds) {
   _apply<unsigned int>(0u, Typelist<Ds...>{}, ds...);
}
```

This works on every compiler.

Answer (score 0):

So I played with the code a bit and came up with 3 versions:

Compiles in clang, fails with gcc:

```
template <class..., class... Us>
void foo(Typelist<>, Typelist<Us...>, Us... us ){ /*do the stuff*/ }

template <class T, class... Ts, class... Us>
void foo(Typelist<T, Ts...>, Typelist<Us...>, T t, Ts... ts, Us... us){
    foo(Typelist<Ts...>{}, Typelist<Us..., Us...>{}, ts..., us..., (us+t)...);
}

template <class... Ts>
void bar(Ts... ts){
    foo(Typelist<Ts...>{}, Typelist<unsigned>{}, ts..., 0u);
}
```

Interesting, both typelist are required for this to work, although it seems that just one would be enough to resolve the ambiguity.

Next one is from Barry's answer. It compiles with gcc, but fails with clang  for me:

```
template<class... Is>
void foo(Is..., Typelist<>) { /*do the stuff*/ }

template<class... Is, class D0, class... Ds>
void foo(Is... is, Typelist<D0, Ds...> , D0 d0, Ds... ds) {
    foo<Is..., decltype(std::declval<Is>()+std::declval<D0>())...>(
                is...,
                (is+d0)...,
                Typelist<Ds...>{},
                ds...);
}

template<class... Ds>
void bar(Ds... ds) {
    foo<unsigned int>(0u, Typelist<Ds...>{}, ds...);
}
```

And finally the one working with both gcc(5.4, 6.3) and clang(3.9):

```
template<class... Us>
struct foo_impl<Typelist<>, Typelist<Us...>>{
    auto operator()(Us... us)-> void { /*do the stuff here*/ }
};

template<class T, class... Ts, class... Us>
struct foo_impl<Typelist<T, Ts...>, Typelist<Us...>>{
    auto operator()(T t, Ts... ts, Us... us)-> void{
        foo_impl<Typelist<Ts...>, Typelist<Us..., Us...>>{}(ts..., us..., (us+t)...);
    }
};

template <class... Ts>
void bar(Ts... ts){
    foo_impl<Typelist<Ts...>, Typelist<unsigned>>{}(ts..., 0u);
}
```

Hope somebody finds this helpful.